# Why does git modify my files? How do i undo it?

Tags: git, github, push, commit

Hey, so I'm a complete git newbie here, the most advanced thing I've done is just basic pulls/pushes .etc

For reasons I don't understand one of my commits  edited a heap of files, including embedded into the file the edits I made since the last commit, for example:

foo.txt:

```
bar
```

then if i edited it to:

```
foobar
```

the file upon committing got changed to something like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
bar
=======
foobar
>>>>>>> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

with the X's being the commit code or whatever.

What are these edits to my source files, and how do I get rid of them?

Thanks for any help with this

Comment: These are merge conflicts. They happen during merge (which is part of `pull`) when the merged branches both have modifications to the same part of a file. They should never be committed by git, but if you `add` unresolved file manually, git will silently obey your (incorrect in this case) command. If you write what *exactly* you did, you may get explanation why they happened in your particular case.

Comment: I just recently reinstalled my OS, did a fresh pull to get the whole project and it was already like that so it probably happened previously. Is there any easy way to resolve the conflicts by overwriting with all the newest edits? I understand that's a really bad idea when working with a team as it could lose a lot of work but right now I'm doing this solo so there's no risk of the conflicts being other people's work.

Comment: There are no latest edits, because the two versions in the conflict were creating in parallel. Use `gitk` to inspect the history and than you'll have to manually select which version is correct for each conflict.

Comment: Is there a simple way to mark the "new version" as the correct one for all files? Basically the old versions are all months old and all the new versions are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those represent merge conflicts. Your commit is causing conflicts to the file.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
bar
```

represents what is already in the HEAD

```
foobar
>>>>>>> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

shows what you are trying to merge.

Look here at Resolving a Merge section: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: How would I go about resolving those conflicts? I'm now thinking it works nothing like I thought it did, if there's a difference between files, shouldn't a new commit be a new version of that file?

Comment: While comiting itself wouldn't cause the conflicts, it is only when merging ( pull does a merge ) do you get conflict. Can you update your question with entire workflow?

Comment: Basically all I know I did that could be significant is:
1) make some edits
2) make a commit
3) push the commit
Then after reinstalling;
1) pull the repo
2) make some edits
3) commit
4) push commit

Now I'm where I am

Comment: ok so after reading http://book.git-scm.com/3_basic_branching_and_merging.html, I get what I've done wrong and I get the conflict markers. All I'd like now is a way to force some sort of overwrite merge, with all conflicts merging the newer commit over the older one. Obviously it wouldn't be a good idea to do that on a large project though

Comment: Depending on what you were doing you can do something like `git pull -Xtheirs` where X denotes the strategy option ( strategy being recursive by default)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to manojlds:

You can specify to have the version of the common ancestor in your merge conflict (separated by pipes |||||), by using the following configuration:

```
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

This would make the conflict look like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
roses are #ff0000
violets are #0000ff
|||||||
roses are red
violets are blue
=======
Roses are red,
Violets are blue,
>>>>>>> master
```

Check out more on [Kevin's Blog](http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2010/09/painless-merge-conflict-resolution-in.html)